# Error on uploading file using webdriver in firefox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

To upload image on the field in this URL: http://demoqa.com/registration/ 
I used the following code that works on chrome but not on Firefox. May I please know the reason and solution?

```
 WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
       driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://demoqa.com/registration/");

WebElement elementUpload=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='profile_pic_10']"));
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementUpload));

elementUpload.sendKeys("D:\\roboraid.jpg");
```

Error shown here is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: File not found: C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

Comment: xpath is not correct: ty this //*[@id='profile_pic_10'], also may be your file is not present there

Comment: I picked up the the file path from its property so this cannot be wrong

Comment: so it is issue of file placing, you got error file not found in error log, can isend u the snap shot of my output

Comment: yes sure you can

Comment: aslo change the name of folder name as samplespace

Comment: change the location and try again

Answer (score 0):

try this code with xpath with Explicit wait:

```
WebDriver   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://demoqa.com/registration/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement elementUpload=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='profile_pic_10']"));
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementUpload));

elementUpload.sendKeys("D:\\1504857398686.png");
```

Please find output image: [image: Output Upload]

Comment: You try and let me know i can place a code as same place as ur location and try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153949/discussion-between-rabia-asif-and-iamsankalp89).

Answer (score 0):

try replacing spaces in the file location

from

```
  C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

to

```
 C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample_Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Change the `xpath` to the below one and try. It worked for me.

```
 //input[@name='profile_pic_10' and @type='file']
```

May I know the browser and environment details which you have tried?

Comment: FF version 55.0.3 selenium version 3.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was the issue with geckodriver of firefox

refer :-

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659

You need to update your geckodriver

OR

Use chromedriver as below

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Workspace\\StackOverlow\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver( );
        driver.get("http://demoqa.com/registration/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scroll(0,300)");
        WebElement elementUpload=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='profile_pic_10']"));
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementUpload));
        elementUpload.sendKeys("D:"+File.separator+"22.jpeg");
```

Comment: This issue is related to geckodriver for latest ff browser. I am also getting same with 3.5/3.4 and 55 ff along with gecko 1.8..  while same code is working with chrome

Comment: what OS you are using?

Comment: gecko version ? .. I m using 0.18 .. I am on win 10

Comment: v0.18.0 of gecko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153971/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-shubham-jain).